# how to show the database value in select box in UI page

Tags: php, html

I want to show my database value in Select box using php..

My code here:

**SQL query**

$home =mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM LOCATION WHERE LOCATION_ID = '$updatehomeid'" )

or die (mysql_error());

```
$homeresult = mysql_fetch_array($home);
```

**Php**

```
$state = $homeresult['STATE'];
```

**Html**

```html
<select name="state" id="countySel2" class="choose" size="1"><option value="<?php echo $state; ?>" selected="selected">Select State</option></select>
```

How to show `db` value in this select box. Please anyone help

Thanks for advance

Comment: where is your db query.It seams you have not get value in your option.

Comment: $office =mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM LOCATION WHERE LOCATION_ID = '$officeid '" )or die (mysql_error());
    $officeresult = mysql_fetch_array($office);

Answer (score 0):

in order to show the string on the select menu you should use:

```
<select name="state" id="countySel2" class="choose" size="1"><option value="<?php echo $state; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $state; ?></option></select>
```

the value is not shown in the UI, its what the server gets

Answer (score 0):

You need while loop and need to echo `<?php echo $state; ?>` in your option

```
 <select name="state" id="countySel2" class="choose" size="1">    
 <option value="Select">Select State</option>    
 <?php  while ($homeresult = mysql_fetch_array($home)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $homeresult['STATE']; ?>"><?php echo $homeresult['STATE']; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: okk print_r($homeresult); inside your while loop and check what it return

Answer (score 0):

This may Help You...

```
<?php
     $qry = "select * from country";
?>
<select>
    <?php
        while($result = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $result['state']; ?>"><?php echo $result['state']; ?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Its show all the database value in single select box... i want show only particular value only

Comment: yeah, i have forgotten to put arguments to `$hm` that must be like `$hm['state']`, watch out, it will Work.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP

```
<?php $home =mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM LOCATION WHERE LOCATION_ID = '$updatehomeid'" ) or die (mysql_error());if($home){while{$homeresult=mysql_fetch_array($home){$state = $homeresult['STATE'];}}?>
```

### HTML

```
<select><option value="<?php echo $state;?>"><?php echo $state;?></option></select>
```

Comment: Its working... If fresh user use this page means show undefined variable... how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
<?php 

$homeid = $_POST['home_id'] or $_GET['home_id'];
if($homeid == '') {
    $homeid = '3' // define default location id from database to prevent undefined value for fresh user 
}

$home = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM LOCATION WHERE LOCATION_ID = '$homeid'" ) or die (mysql_error());

if($home){while{$homeresult=mysql_fetch_array($home){$state = $homeresult['STATE'];}}

?>

<select><option value="<?php echo $state;?>"><?php echo $state;?></option></select>
```